# ¿Cómo eliminar atributo de documento XML c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Necesitó eliminar  atributos de un documento XML guardado en una ubicación en mi PC

Ejemplo eliminar el atributo Type

```
-<ds:Signature Id="Signature-15d7c3e9-a6b4-48be-a9a5-70cbef9dd03d"  Type=”ak47” xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Escribí esto pero no me está funcionando:

```
private string SetAtributo(XmlDocument xmlDoc,string prefix,string uri,string pathSintax,string atributo)
    {
        string result = "";
        try
        {
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(path);
            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsManager.AddNamespace(prefix,uri);
            XmlNode nodo = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(pathSintax, nsManager);
            if (nodo != null)
            {
               //CODIGO QUE NECESITO
            }
         xmlDoc.Save(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { result = ex.ToString(); }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si ya tienes seleccionado el nodo no tendrías más que usar el método `RemoveNamedItem` de la colección `Attributes`:

```
nodo.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem(atributo);
```